# jQuery Flip! Plugin - revertFlip() not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Forgive me if the answer seems too obvious, I'm really new to jQuery. I'm trying use the [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) plugin on my webpage, but for some reason, after the user clicks the `<li>` the second time, the content isn't reverted, but instead, the same flip function is used, therefore rendering the same result. I want the user to be able to flip back and forth at will. Here is my code:

jQuery

```
$('.class').click(
    function() {
        $(this).flip({
            direction: 'lr',
            content: $('p', this).html(),
            speed: 200,
        })
    },
    function() {
        $(this).revertFlip()
    }
);
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li class="class">
        <span class="image">
            <img src="images/jquery-small.png" alt="">
        </span>
        <p>
            <span class="content">blah blah blah</span>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` does not take two function references. I think you're looking for [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (which does):

```
$('.class').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).flip({
            direction: 'lr',
            content: $('p', this).html(),
            speed: 200,
        })
    },
    function() {
        $(this).revertFlip()
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2WdqD/

(In the example I changed the "content" to make it more obvious that it is working)

Comment: thanks! Not only did I get my answer, but I learned a little bit more!